# Prove, that $\vec{\phi }(t)=e^{\lambda_0t} \cdot \vec{x}_0 $ is a solution to the system $X'=AX$

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

If $\lambda_0$ is an eigenvalue of matrix $A$, corresponding to eigenvector $\vec{x}_0$, then vectorfunction $\vec{\phi}(t)=e^{\lambda_0 t} \cdot \lambda_0 \vec{x}_0$ is a solution to homogeneous system $~X'=AX~$. Do, someone know the name of the theorem and if possible where to find the proof with detailed explanations?

Answer (score 1):

If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then
$$ X(t) = e^{\lambda t} v \implies X'(t) = e^{\lambda t} (\lambda v) = e^{\lambda t} (Av) = A (e^{\lambda t} v) =  AX(t), $$
so $X$ solves the differential equation.

Comment: Do you know the title of the theorem? Because I don't understand the proof you gave either.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't have a name. You can read more about it, e.g. on this website: https://www.math24.net/method-eigenvalues-eigenvectors/. There are some worked examples at the bottom of the page. If that doesn't suffice, just pick up any decent book about differential equations. This theorem will definitely be in there, in a section relating to linear systems of ODE with constant coefficients.